# Can't initialize jNativeHook 2.0

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the library JNativeHook 2.0 to intercept keyboard events, see:

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new Intercept());
    }

}
```

But when i try start the MainApp, i got the error:

```
Fev 12, 2015 9:12:53 PM org.jnativehook.DefaultLibraryLocator getLibraries
Informações: Library extracted successfully: /tmp/libJNativeHook-2.0.0.so (0xE9C5AD25418C597994B824E5A9D62858192227D).

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /tmp/libJNativeHook-2.0.0.so: undefined symbol: hook_set_logger_proc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hook_set_logger_proc should be defined by libuiohook at link-time.  This is probably related to [Issue #43](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues/43).